# Jest, Next JS - Import component is not working when rendering component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, next.js, jestjs

I try to do testing then I render a component but I get error :

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

[image]

This is my test file, component file and some library code

**inputsample.test.js**

```
import InputSample from './inputsample';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

it('render name input sample', async () => {
  const wrapper = render(<InputSample />);
  expect('Test').toEqual('Test');
});
```

**inputsample.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'theme-ui';
import { theme } from 'theme';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'theme-ui';

const InputSample = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Input name="siap" value="siap" />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputSample;
```

**Input.d.ts** (from theme-ui library)

```
import React from 'react';
import { BoxOwnProps } from './Box';
import type { Assign, ForwardRef } from './types';
export interface InputProps extends Assign<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>, BoxOwnProps> {
    autofillBackgroundColor?: string;
}
/**
 * Input variants can be defined in `theme.forms`
 * and the component uses the `theme.forms.input` variant by default.
 * @see https://theme-ui.com/components/input/
 */
export declare const Input: ForwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>;
```

I already follow some solution like changing import from `'{ Component }'` to `'Component'`. It still gets error

***This is my configuration files, if you want to know...***

**jest.config.js**

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './'
});
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '../../node_modules', 'tests'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/jest.setup.js'],

  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '#(.*)': '<rootDir>/node_modules/$1',
    components: '<rootDir>/src/components',
    theme: '<rootDir>/src/theme',
    '^components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^graphql/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/graphql/$1',
    '^domain/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/domain/$1',
    '^utils/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils/$1',
    '^theme/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/theme/$1',
    '^constants/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/constants/$1',
    '^context/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/context/$1',
    '^tests/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/$1',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js'
  }
};
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

jest.setup.js

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```